# Can't assign IPv6 address to CentOS7 VM on Oracle Cloud

Tags: centos7, oracle, oracle-linux

I just can't get to assigning a public IPv6 address to my oracle instance running CentOS 7.

I have assigned IPv6 range to the subnet, and another VM running Ubuntu successfully gets the assigned IPv6.

Output of ifconfig :

```
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
        inet 10.0.0.240  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::17ff:fe01:b1b2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:00:17:01:b1:b2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1298  bytes 1235123 (1.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1207  bytes 810530 (791.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: Which log exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. On Oracle Cloud you must assign a /128 IPv6 address to the VM and once this is done you can rely on dhclient to get it set up:

```
dhclient -6 ens3
```

Comment: The VM successfully picked up the IP, but not the default gateway. I still can't ping any IPv6 address through the VM ! Also, the IP is released on reboot. I am unable to make any changes to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3 permanent. Please guide me further.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `systemctl disable rhel-import-state` to prevent overwriting `/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-ens3`
2. Add `DHCPV6C=yes` to `ifcfg-ens3`
3. In "Networking -> Virtual Cloud Networks -> <your vcn> -> Security List Details" add Ingress and Egress rules for IPv6. At least egress.
4. Reboot and enjoy

Comment: please update your answer as I believe he wants to have a static address

Comment: Doing the above, now I do get an IPv6 address on ens3, however there's no internet connectivity.

ping6 to any address fails with : network is unreachable.

Comment: Here's my ifcfg-ens3 contents :

NAME="ens3"
DEVICE="ens3"
ONBOOT=yes
NETBOOT=yes
UUID="80ccc011-c41d-496a-adc3-xxxxxxx"
IPV6INIT=yes
DHCPV6C=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
TYPE=Ethernet
NM_CONTROLLED=no